# Of vs. for in a given context with reasons

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, prepositions, word-difference

Which of these is correct when replying to an e-mail requesting specific details:

> Please find enclosed the required details of XXX team

or

> Please find enclosed the required details for XXX team

(The *XXX* is the name of the team working on a specific project)

The second sounds right to me, though I cannot place why. I would like to know which is right and why.

Answer (score 1):

If the recipient of the email plans to give the details to the XXX team, then the enclosed plans are **for** the team.

If XXX team wrote the plans, and you are sending them to someone else, then the enclosed place are **of** the team – although *from* could work in that context as well.

In short, either preposition might be correct, but it depends on where the plans came from and who they are going to.

Comment: It may helpful to note that “to” and “for” are frequently interchangeable when they they are in the dative. “I bought a present to give to you; I brought a present for you”.